# Composer can not connect to repo.packagist.org:443

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-7, packagist

whene i run `composer u` , in laravel receive this error :

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
https://repo.packagist.org could not be fully loaded (curl error 35 while downloading https://repo.packagist.org
/packages.json: OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to repo.packagist.org:443 ), package inform
ation was loaded from the local cache and may be out of date
```

I feel that it says "**I can't connect to the repo.packagist.org**"

version laravel : 7
php : 7.2.5
composer : 2.4.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run
`composer config -g repo.packagist composer https://packagist.org`

resource = [laracasts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKKsM.png)

---

if not worked, turn 'on' or 'off' VPN.

---

and if still the problem not resolved check this page and changing your DNS. it was me worked!

https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/9376#issuecomment-718921358

[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).